# CSS anchor text not in line

Tags: css, html-lists, anchor, inline

This is my site:
http://www.michelepierri.it/

I correctly see my theme in FF and IE but if I open it in Chrome menu voice are not correctly visualized:

[image]

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: You've set `line-height` to your menu items to have them vertically centered. Those two options break their text into two lines so second line gets much much lower. And also **define correctly**. How should it be displayed. In one line, in two lines but closer to each other?

Comment: no problems here in Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52

Comment: @Mark: I'm not sure which version of Chrome you're using, but mine (v24) shows exactly the same problem as seen on the image.

Comment: Try to disable javascripts and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing your css, I found too many unused styling please remove those and use these rules:

```
.menu li {
float: left;
}
.menu a {
white-space: nowrap;
border-left: 1px solid #585858;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 700;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
padding: 0 0.9em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #242424;
}
```

Please see the attachment after doing that changes.

[image]

See I am also using the same version and for me its fine

[image]

Comment: I agree that this site is in a serious state of mess in terms of CSS. It should be consolidated severely. I'd rather remove it completely in start writing in anew using *object oriented style paradigm*.

Comment: Which version of chrome you are using ?

Comment: Who? OP or me? I'm using v24. I don't have a clue what OP is using.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Still trying to find the UI issue.

Comment: Didn't you just suggest a solution to the OP that resolves the issue? Are you trying to say that when you access that page, you don't see the issue at all or what? Because the issue is definitely there. I see it as well on exactly the same Chrome version. I find the combination of your answer and comments confusing...

Answer (score 1):

### Prevent menu options from wrapping text

Add an additional style rule to your menu links CSS so all text stays in the same line.

```
.menu a {
    border-left: 1px solid #585858;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0.9em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #242424;

    white-space: nowrap; /* THIS ONE */
}
```

And add the same thing to `.sub-header-menu a` style definition because when I check the site even *Cloud Computing* is wrapped and breaks the whole situation.

> ***Advice**: It is ok that you're exploring the possibilities of CSS but you're playing a bit too much with it producing legibility problems. Letter and word spacing should only be cautiously manipulated. I'd suggest to remove majority of letter and word spacing settings.*